# Правильное масштабирование фона

Tags: css

Не могу найти правильное решение моей задачи. нужно относительно размера масштабировать картинку фона(т.е. что бы хотя бы раз она была в полном размере).

для картинок размер которых больше экрана можно использовать

```
       background-size: 100% auto;
```

но если картинка меньше экрана, то она просто растягивается. а мне этого не нужно.

как это можно сделать средствами css?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size

    background-size: [ <значение> | <проценты> | auto ]{1,2} | cover | contain

Comment: @Yura Ivanov а пример можно?

Comment: @M11, можно, конечно. по ссылке пройдите, там пример.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov мне бы именно так
 
      background-size: [ <значение> | <проценты> | auto ]{1,2} | cover | contain

Comment: А мне нравится, что растягивается.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробую объяснить на пальцах. ([тут можно потрогать руками рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/DnV4m/))

Если написать вот так:

```
.demo {
    background-image: url(cat.png);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;        
}
```

Мы передадим такие пожелания браузеру:

- Вставь на фон блока с классом "demo" картинку с котиком
- Размести ее, по возможности, в центре этого блока
- Не надо использовать свойство "замостить", если фоновая картинка меньше этого блока

Немного уточним пожелания:

```
.first {
    background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

- Хочу, чтобы фоновое изображение было 100 на 100 пикселей; масштабировать не надо; пропорции сохранять не надо

---

Попробуем иначе:

```
.second {
    background-size: contain;
}
```

- Хочу, чтобы фоновое изображение заняло максимальную область блока, при которой сохранит свои пропорции и будет видно целиком

---

И последний вариант:

```
.third {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

- Хочу, чтобы фоновое изображение закрыло блок целиком, оно не обязательно должно быть видно целиком, главное, чтобы сохранились пропорции

*Поскольку мы в самом начале указывали расположение фонового изображения в центре блока, в первую очередь будет видна центральная часть изображения. Это можно изменить с помощью свойства **background-position***

Что в итоге получится (первый, второй и третий примеры один под одним):

[image: Пример работы background-size]