# Как сделать масштабирование изображения под размер экрана без скролла страницы?

Tags: html, jquery, css

на сайте http://mirmitino.ru/plans  изображение используется как фон [image]

и оно растягивается под размер экрана видимо под размер блока class="resizable div_100" как это сделано?

Comment: Здесь несколько нюансов, скажете изображение чего? И исправьте вопрос, приведите пример нормальный.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Адаптивный фон с absolute](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536671/%d0%90%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd-%d1%81-absolute)

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko там суть вопроса в другом и в вопросе лишние правила для этого случаю.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan создай минимальный пример сам, если автор не хочет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильное масштабирование фона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/302900/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

1. Без прокрутки

```css
body {
  background: url(http://mirmitino.ru/assets/images/vk/plans.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

1.1. Без повторения фона при узком окне, так же как на http://mirmitino.ru/plans

```css
body {
  background: url(http://mirmitino.ru/assets/images/vk/plans.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

2. Есть прокрутка

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://mirmitino.ru/assets/images/vk/plans.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Растянуть изображения на всю ширину и высоту окна браузера можно с помощью следующих CSS стилей:
https://jsfiddle.net/s4d8917n/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://mirmitino.ru/assets/images/vk/plans.jpg" />
```

Comment: Лол, я так же отвечал в прошлый раз. Этот вопрос удаляли неделю назад.

Comment: C `height: 100vh;` изображение искажается, а без него есть прокрутка.

Comment: @Alex78191 в добавленном вами сниппете прокрутка есть и по горизонтали тоже)

Comment: @andreymal и что? это вообще не мой ответ

Comment: @Alex78191 а сниппет ваш

Comment: @andreymal и что? Это сайт неправильно тег body отображает.

Comment: @Alex78191 он (и jsfiddle тоже) всё правильно отображает, у него всегда есть отступы по умолчанию. Быть может, автор ответа неявно подразумевал (или забыл дописать) `margin: 0; padding: 0;`, чего в сниппете нету

Comment: Исправь, если много знаешь

Comment: @andreymal достаточно `margin: 0; `

Comment: @andreymal из-за полосы прокрутки `100vh` работает не так как нужно..